# Restringir usuário "Autor" a ver somente as imagens que ele envia

Tags: wordpress, plugin, woocommerce

preciso da ajuda de vocês para fazer com que o usuário "Autor" tenha restrições somente para visualizar as mídias que ele envia.

Normalmente o Autor tem acesso a todas as imagens enviadas por todos os usuários e preciso restringir esse acesso a somente as imagens que ele próprio enviar, de forma que ele crie sua própria vitrine e administre somente ela.

Só para constar estou utilizando o tema Storefront que é um Woocommerce e quero que os clientes cadastrados (que estão por padrão para serem cadastrados como autor) administrem somente suas próprias vitrines de produtos.

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Ola, Caio Felipe, o primeiro código que vc mostrou, que restringe a visualização de toda a biblioteca de media, onde deve ser inserido? em function.php?

Comment: @RaelRodrigues insere o código no function.php também. Qualquer modificação externa relativa a scripts vai no function.php. Recomendo que por segurança faça uma cópia do código antes de postar qualquer coisa no function.php pois pode bugar seu código e o site sair do ar. Caso isso aconteça vc tem a opção de abrir o arquivo pelas pastas e colar o código que estava funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo do pressuposto de que o usuário terá **sempre** o *role* "Author", você pode restringir a biblioteca de media usando o [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) chamado [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Para efeitos didáticos, *actions* - de maneira bem simples - são coisas que ocorrem na terra do WP. Você pode fazer o gancho (*hook*, em inglês) de alguns métodos nesses *actions*, para garantir que o referido método ocorra no momento dessa ação. Estamos interessados no *pre_get_posts* porque o WP, para preencher a página da biblioteca com as imagens, faz uma consulta buscando posts que tem imagens. O pulo do gato está em, antes dessa consulta ser feita (por isso o prefixo "*pre*"), a gente incluir uma alteração nos parâmetros dessa consulta, restringindo por autor. Em termos de código, isso se traduz em

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'restringir_biblioteca' );
function restringir_biblioteca($wp_query_obj){
    global $current_user, $pagenow;
    if(!is_a($current_user, 'WP_User')){
        return;
    }
    if ('admin-ajax.php' != $pagenow or $_REQUEST['action'] != 'query-attachments'){
        return;
    }
    if(!current_user_can('manage_media_library')){
        $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->ID);
        return;
    }
}
```

As duas primeiras comparações são feitas para garantir que o usuário é um usuário, que estamos na página do admin do WP e de que estamos na biblioteca (*query-attachments*). O segredo mora na terceira comparação: Por padrão, o usuário de *role* "Author" **não** pode administrar toda a biblioteca de mídia (ou, em inglês, *manage the media library* - eis o nome da *capability*). Por isso, `!current_user_can('manage_media_library')` vai ser `true`. Nesse momento, é dito para o objeto da `WP_Query`, que mais um parâmetro deve ser passado pra ele, isto é, o `ID` do usuário (ou "Author") em questão. Como foi usado *pre_get_posts*, essa adição é feita, e logo em seguida, a consulta é feita. Isso faz com que apenas as imagens daquele autor em específico apareçam na biblioteca.

**ADENDO**

Como que você quer que cada autor administre apenas a sua própria vitrine, eu suponho que seja interessante que os autores também só possam visualizar os seus próprios posts, e os de mais ninguém (por padrão, o WP deixa que o "Author" visualise - mas não edite - posts de outros autores. Meu próximo método elimina essa funcionalidade). Para isso, pode-se utilizar a *action* chamada [parse_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query). Existem outras maneiras de se fazer isso, e essa não é a mais eficiente, mas já resolve o problema.

A lógica é basicamente a mesma que a anterior. Eu verifico que o usuário ("Author") **não** tem poderes do *role* "Editor" e, portanto, modifico a *query* para filtrar apenas os posts que ele criou. Segue

```
add_action('parse_query', 'restringe_posts' );
function restringe_posts( $wp_query ){
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/upload.php' ) !== false || strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit.php' ) !== false ) {
        if (!current_user_can('level_5' )){
            global $current_user;
            $wp_query->set('author', $current_user->id);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Pra restringir mais ainda o resultado, você pode atribuir outros valores pra *query*. Isso é feito usando-se novamente do método `set()`. Busquei em seu [código fonte](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2369), e o método só aceita um par de valores por vez, e não um array, como seria mais interessante. Portando, você deve chamá-lo novamente. Para o caso de `post_type => product`, basta você incluir

```
$wp_query_obj->set('post_type', 'product');
```

e

```
$wp_query->set('post_type', 'product');
```

em cada um dos dois métodos, respectivamente, logo abaixo da primeira ocorrência do método `set()`. Você pode incluir não só o parâmetro `post_type`, mas sim todos os que a [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) permite.

Comment: Ok Caio, ficou bem claro para mim, mas preciso saber agora onde incluo esse método, no functions.php ou no header.php?

Comment: @DimitriMarchetti no functions.php do seu tema deve funcionar

Comment: como eu faria para modificar esse código para restringir o post_type products? Olhando aqui a biblioteca de mídias está restrita, mas como estou utilizando um tema woocommerce preciso restringir o post_type products também, ou seja os produtos postados, para que o autor veja somente seus próprios produtos postados.

Comment: @DimitriMarchetti vou editar a resposta